# Adding a new font in magento admin panel

Tags: css, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7

we have list of fonts available in the text editor of magento using which we can create cms pages.I need to add a new font to that, is it possible.?

Comment: not overly familiar with magento but you can try adding a new font by generating one with this http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator so long as you have permission to use the font

Answer (score 0):

You can add the font options via the tiny_mce editor_template.js file:

File: js\tiny_mce\themes\advanced\editor_template.js

Variable: theme_advanced_fonts

[Tinymce Config](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_fonts)

Comment: If you're using a @font-face declaration you'll also need to put that in a css file that is read by the page, for example: /skin/adminhtml/default/default/custom.css